# Revert Change sets

Tags: apex, change-set, production

I want to roll back apex class updates which I deployed via change set.

Is there a way where I can revert the Inbound Changes sets from production?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

There is [this idea for it](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdeW6UAJ/change-sets-should-allow-for-rollback), and it's 10 years old, so Salesforce might actually look at it at some time in the next decade, maybe.

Your only recourse for now is to hope you have a copy of this code either backed up/stored locally, in version control, or in another sandbox, and then do another set of deployments to re-deploy the old code.

If you haven't gotten version control (e.g. Git) and Salesforce DX set up yet, now would be a fine time to do so. Being able to see and revert changes is one of the things version control is good for. Version control alone won't let you revert changes *in Salesforce*, so that's where Salesforce DX (i.e. the Salesforce CLI) comes into play (in that it allows you to deploy the code you have, locally, to your sandboxes and/or production instance).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer is to use one of the highly regarded devops vendor packages like [Gearset](https://gearset.com/blog/gearset-and-change-sets/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAgribBhDkARIsAASA5buMNK3-1q9Uym9XWBi7HiFiHQQ1iEl386qlnvhciDpbeLC7rEn2TRgaAnTgEALw_wcB) or [Copado](https://docs.copado.com/articles/#!copado-ci-cd-publication/copado-rollback) that include built-in rollback for any deployment.